# How to Implement generics in database insert?

Tags: c#, generics

I can't come up with proper title of that question. If someone think he can give a better name he is free to change it. I have the following piece of code:

```
string xmlFilePath = pathFromserverFolder + "/articles.xml";
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Articles));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath);
Articles articles = (Articles)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
//connection to db
connection.DeleteAll<Article>();
List<Article> allArticles = articles.All;
connection.InsertAll(allArticles);
int numArticlesImported = connection.Table<Article>().ToList().Count;
```

In the place of Article and Articles I want to put another class types for example Customer and Customers, Group and Groups etcetera. In order not to repeat the piece of code I just pasted `n` times I want to put that code in a method that recieves the type Article and Articles or the other pairs and make the exact same operations every time. Articles contains list of Article, Customers contains list of Customer etcetera. Every plural class type contains All property. Is it possible to do what I want in C# and how?

Comment: Maybe you should use generics?

Comment: Guess thats is the purpose of the tags he used. Is trying to ask how to implement generics in that code block. Gonna suggest an edit

Comment: The proper title could be: How to generalize the type ?

Comment: Yes, it come to my mind, but how exactly? The examples I find in internet seem not to do what I want.

Comment: If you are before creating new files you can also consider generating class to represent your software layers using T4 text templates. There you would be able to do some magic with types rotation (assuming the code is identical - most comfortable case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a generic method with two generic arguments, where the second one is the plural class that contains a common `All`-property:

```
void DoSomething<T, U>(string xmlFileName) where U: IPlural<T> where T: new()
{
    string xmlFilePath = pathFromserverFolder + "/" + xmlFileName;
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFilePath);
    U u = (U)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    textReader.Close();
    //connection to db
    connection.DeleteAll<T>();
    List<T> all = u.All;
    connection.InsertAll(all);
    int numArticlesImported = connection.Table<T>().ToList().Count;
}
interface IPlural<T>
{
    List<T> All { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
DoSomething<Article, Articles>("articles.xml");
```

However this assumes `Articles` to implement the `IPlural<Article>`-interface.

Comment: I get two errors on `u.All` :
`Cannot convert method group 'All' to non-delegate type 'List<T>'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`
and on `connection.Table<T>()`
`'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLiteConnection.Table<T>()'`

Comment: @Profile3ForStack Sorry, forgot the second generic constraint. You need `where U: IPlural<T> where T: new()`.

Comment: On line `public List<T> All { get; set; }`  I get error `The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item`

Comment: IPlural should be IEnumerable. Was about to add an almost identical answer, suggesting an edit in your answer

Comment: @bradbury9 I rejected your edit, as an `IEnumerable<T>` has no `All`-member, making the code not compile any more.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Indeed, is a function not a property. I wonder if OP code ever compiled... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx